Compressing partitioned tables in Oracle 19c
I am compressing partitioned tables.
before partitioned tables, I tried normal tables with the follwoing steps:
DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE(
    uname => 'USER',
    orig_table => 'ORIGINAL',
    int_table => 'INTERIM'
);




BEGIN
   DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE('USER','ORIGINAL', DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID);
END;
/



BEGIN
   DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE(
      uname => 'USER',
      orig_table => 'ORIGINAL',
      int_table => 'INTERIM',
      options_flag => DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID);
END;
/



DECLARE
   error_count pls_integer := 0;
BEGIN
   DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS('USER', 'ORIGINAL', 'INTERIM', dbms_redefinition.cons_orig_params, TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE, error_count);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('errors := ' || TO_CHAR(error_count));
END;
/


DECLARE
   error_count pls_integer := 0;
BEGIN
DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS(
    uname => 'USER',
    orig_table => 'ORIGINAL',
    int_table => 'INTERIM',
    copy_indexes => DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_ORIG_PARAMS,
    copy_triggers => TRUE,
    copy_constraints => TRUE,
    copy_privileges => TRUE,
    ignore_errors => FALSE,
    num_errors => 0
);
END;
/

ALTER TABLE ORIGINAL MOVE ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED;

However, for partitioned tables, this is not possible.
can someone tell me the procedure to compress partitioned tables in Oracle 19c?

Fixed it.
The above steps will indeed be followed (DBMS_REDEFINITION).
However, if your table has partitioned indexes, you will need to drop them.
-- Check indexes
SELECT index_name
FROM all_indexes
WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
AND partitioned = 'YES';


-- Copy DDL of the index

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX','index_name', 'schema') FROM DUAL;

-- Drop index(s)

DROP INDEX index_name;

BEGIN
   DBMS_REDEFINITION.sync_interim_table(
      uname => 'SCHEMA',
      orig_table => 'table_name',
      int_table => 'MY_INTERIM_TABLE'
   );
END;
/


BEGIN
   DBMS_REDEFINITION.finish_redef_table(
      uname => 'SCHEMA',
      orig_table => 'table_name',
      int_table => 'MY_INTERIM_TABLE'
   );
END;
/

